# How to send automatically mails in intents?

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, android-edittext

This is some code I have:

```
public void sendIt(View view){    
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String string = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "mymail@domain.com"); 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is the subject.");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is extra text.");
    ...
}
```

I want that if this method is called it opens an E-mailapp and a mail with as subject: "This is the subject." and as text: "This is the extra text." That does the app so that's correct.

But I want too that automatically the field "Send to" cointains mymail@domain.com. That doesn't my app. How to do that?

What may be other fine is that it too automatically sends the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to add `EXTRA_EMAIL` :

`intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mymail@domain.com"});`

It works fine for me. Try and notify whether it helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public void sendIt(View view){    
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String string = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "mymail@domain.com" });
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is the subject.");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is extra text.");
    ...
}
```